# Launching Node packages.json scripts from Embedded Terminal in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, yeoman, jetbrains-ide, yo

In WebStorm 2016.2.2 for Windows 7 Professional x64, I would like to go to `Tools->Run Gulp/Grunt/npm Task` and be able to launch npm tasks from the embedded terminal.

The reason is I am running a yo generator which requires use of the arrow keys to select multiple-choice option outputs, and the default terminal (Run Windows) that WebStorm launches does not support this, but the Embedded Terminal (`Alt+F12`) functions exactly as intended. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK no other way than opening Terminal window and typing required command manually.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up prepending 'start' to open up a separate terminal window.
For example:     `"scripts":{"testCmd" : "start cmd.exe @cmd /k \"echo \"hello there\" && exit 1\""}`

This opens the command line natively in Windows, prints "hello there", and closes the command line window.